# How to draw corners and shadows on sections in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to create **sections** with shadows and a corner radius using a `UICollectionView` like shown below:

[image: example]

Is there an API available with `UICollectionView` to manipulate a section directly **instead of manipulating the cells**?

AFAIK nearly all answers on stackoverflow are based on tracking the `indexPath` and setting the `cell.layer.cornerRadius` accordingly (e.g. the top cell will render a radius and the bottom one will).

I'm looking for an approach where this is done outside the cell, perhaps using the `UICollectionViewLayout` although I'm not sure which API would make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no such API, I would recommend you to use multiple tableViews (which are easy to modify according to your wishes)  instead of one tableView divided in sections.

Answer (score 0):

Your collectionView can contain cell that contains tableView. Your number of items on the collectionView will be the number of sections. Then the collectionViewCell will have a View with rounded corner and shadow and inside the tableView